# Why is the partial derivative of a piecewise function undefined in a given domain?

Tags: calculus

For the piecewise function
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(x-y)^{-2}&\text{if $y\leq3\leq x$ and $y\leq5\leq x$,} \\ 
0&\text{otherwise,} 
\end{cases}
$$
why is the partial derivative with respect to $x$, which is $-2(x-y)^3$, undefined  when $y\leq3$ and $x=5$? My thought is that the denominator can grow uncontrollably large with $x$ fixed at $5$ and $y$ going to negative infinity.

Comment: That's a strange way of writing the cases! The condition is equivalent to $y \le 3$ and $5 \le x$, and if you draw a picture of that region, perhaps you'll see why.

Comment: is there an algebraic explanation without the use of graph?

Comment: Yes, of course. But to find it, you need to realize how the division into cases works, and for me the easiest way to do that is to first draw a picture.